# Different sounds for chat messages and chat messages for you

Tags: feature-request, chat

Sometimes on chat I set it to play an audio notification upon a message being posted (not just a message with my name).  This can get confusing, because I like having some kind of feedback upon a message being posted but I would like a distinction between the sounds so that I know if it was a message for me.

The way this would probably best work is to keep the noise for when a message contains your @tag and the new noise would be for any other message.  This way it would be less confusing for current members of the site.  Instead we could make a new noise for the any other message.

This way you can know whether there is a message in a chat and whether it is directed to you without having to check the chat window.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to set chat to make a noise for every comment. *Off to investigate.*